# Can I make `new X()` in Java return a dynamic proxy?

Tags: java, reflection, proxy

I know I can write a dynamic proxy like this:

```
public class DecoratedFile implements java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler {

    private Object delegate;

    public static Object newInstance(Object delegate) {
        return java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
              obj.getClass().getClassLoader(),
              obj.getClass().getInterfaces(),
              new DecoratedFile (delegate));
    }

    private DecoratedFile (Object delegate) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args)
       throws Throwable
    {
        ... do something to `delegate`
    }
}
```

... which can be instantiated like so:

```
  File decorated = DecoratedFile.newInstance(new File("README.txt"));
```

Is there a way to write a class such that I can instantiate a dynamic proxy using the "new" keyword:

```
  File decorated = new DecoratedFile(new File("README.txt"));
```

For example, to refactor a non-dynamic implementation without affecting its clients.

If the answer is "no, you can't" -- is there a design principle behind this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "to refactor a non-dynamic implementation without affecting its clients". What would you gain by being able to do `new DecoratedFile()` rather than `DecoratedFile.newInstance()`?

Comment: @JBNizet imagine I already have an implementation of DecoratedFile in a library that other people use. Dozens of users of that library have `new DecoratedFile()` peppered through their code. If I change it to need `DecoratedFile.newInstance()` I break backward compatibility.

Comment: `File` is not a `final` class, you can extend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The 'design principle behind it' is that the JLS says so.

What you need is the factory pattern, or the Abstract Factory pattern, whatever the difference between them may be. I've never been able to figure why there  are two of them.